# What type of 1D Barcode is this? And How do you know?

Tags: barcode

This is a barcode off an order form. We have 100's of these to process, and several off the shelf mobile solutions scan it properly, while others fail.

Knowing the barcode type will allow me to narrow my search of capable barcode scanners.

[image: Barcode Type in Question]

Adding a second barcode image, with no border to see if that makes a difference.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: i'm wondering if the border around that image, is affecting the scan? I'll add a new image, with no border.

Comment: Sorry this got closed. Maybe I should have said ... so that I can find an API to scan the (then known) bar code type :(

Comment: Doesn't make it on topic. This has nothing to do with hardware or software.

Comment: You might find Azalea's [What Kind of Barcode is This?](http://www.azalea.com/white-papers/WhatKindOfBarcodeIsThis.pdf) PDF White Paper useful.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be in Code 128 format.

Extra info - although it looks like Code 128 it is poorly printed.  Look at the very wide black bars.  They are incorrect as there should be a one or two white spaces in there.  For Code 128, the widest bar should only be 4x the narrowest bar.  So looks like a printing error and you will never read.

Comment: I was thinking Code 128 format also. Were you able to scan it? I tried scanning it on Psion Teklogix Workabout pro and it wouldn't scan.

Comment: My wife has these types of barcodes at her work (see works as an evidence tech, and I work in IT, so I get questions from her).  She has the same problem with her handheld scanners not reading them... even though they appear to be Code 128 compliant.  I suspect that it could be a quiet zone violation, but have not been able to confirm this. You have to have whitespace of at least 10 widths of the narrowest line to both the left and the right of the barcode.  Could that be the case for you?

Comment: Just a note: My android phone couldn't scan it either. If you happen to find a list of which types are supported, you can narrow it down? I can't seem to find any such list though.

Comment: @Andrew - Don't edit answers to reply to people.  You will find yourself with the inability to edit anything very shortly if you do.